# Getting the position of the Ascending and Descending orbital nodes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orbital-mechanics

I'm working on a space sim and I'm stuck getting the position of the Ascending and Descending orbital nodes. I know how to get the position at any angle of the orbit, but it's measured from the orbit's center, not the orbiting bodies center.

Here is a picture showing what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

How can I get the angle from the center to the two orbital nodes? This is the code I have now. It returns the nodes at the correct angle, but the distance isn't correct.

```
internal Vector3 AscendingNode()
{
    if (orbitalElements.IsHyperbolic())
    {
        return Vector3.zero; // No ascending or descending nodes in a hyperbolic orbit
    }

    var semiMajorAxis = (float)(orbitalElements.semiMajorAxis / Tudat.Instance.unitDivider);

    var semiMinorAxis = semiMajorAxis * Mathf.Sqrt((1 - ((float)orbitalElements.eccentricity * (float)orbitalElements.eccentricity)));
    var inclination = 360 - (float)orbitalElements.inclination * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var longitudeOfAscendingAngle = 360 - (float)orbitalElements.longitudeOfAscending * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    var ascendingAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(longitudeOfAscendingAngle, Vector3.up);
    var inclinationAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(inclination, Vector3.right);

    var position = new Vector3(semiMajorAxis * Mathf.Cos(0), 0.0f, semiMinorAxis * Mathf.Sin(0));
    position = ascendingAngle * (inclinationAngle * (position)) + orbitingBody.GetPosition();

    return position;

}
```

Comment: This looks like a maths question, rather than a programming one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com